# NullReferenceException for a 2d array and a self created class

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I try to check and change a self created structure but I get  NullReferenceException for the elements in the Array. I guess it is a initialisation issue but I can't find the reason.
The code "public newstructure[,] matrix = new newstructure[4, 4];" should initialize but why do I get NullReferenceException when I want to use "matrix[mx, my].first"?

```
public class newstructure { public string first = "text1"; public string second = "text2"; };

public newstructure[,] matrix = new newstructure[4, 4];

public void Check_array(int mx, int my)
    {
        if (matrix[mx, my].first == "text1")
        {
            matrix[mx, my].first = newcontent;
            return;
        }
        if (matrix[mx, my].second == "text2") 
        {
            matrix[mx, my].second = newcontent;
            return;
        }            
        if (Matrix[mx, my].second != "text2") Do_something(mx, my); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the fast answers. I'll try struct instead of class.

Comment: Thanks guys. Struct runs fine.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `newstructure` as a *class*, not as a *structure*. Classes are reference types and unless you explicitly fill your array with instances of the class, all you will get when trying to access array items is null references. Try using `struct` instead of `class` to define your `newstructure` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
public newstructure[,] matrix = new newstructure[4, 4];
```

will initialize a new matrix of `newstructure`s, but they will all be null (since `newstructure` is a reference type), so `matrix[mx, my]` will be `null`, which is why you are getting a `NullReferenceException`.

You will need to initialize each member of the array (or check for null, which is easier).

```
public void Check_array(int mx, int my)
{
    if(matrix[mx, my] == null)
        matrix[mx, my] = new newstructure();

    if (matrix[mx, my].first == "text1")
    {
        matrix[mx, my].first = newcontent;
        return;
    }
    if (matrix[mx, my].second == "text2") 
    {
        matrix[mx, my].second = newcontent;
        return;
    }            
    if (Matrix[mx, my].second != "text2") Do_something(mx, my); 
      //^-- check capitalization here - 'Matrix' and 'matrix' are different identifiers.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (matrix[mx, my] != null)
```

Needs to go around anything you do to it. Also, be careful with the capital M you have in your third if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I suppuse that the NullReferenceException  is about the strings of the class, because you need to initialize in a constructor, like this below one

```
public class newstructure 
{ 
     public string first; 
     public string second; 

     public newstructure()
     {
          first = "text1";
          second = "text2";
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you created Array that "holds" `newstructure` objects.

You need to actually create each array item explicitly:

```
matrix[0, 0] = new newstructure();
matrix[0, 1] = new newstructure();
// ...and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use a 'Constructor'. it will help you to initialize your objects and you will not get exception